# How does ListFragment restore scroll position after destroyView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

Suppose we have two fragments – `ListFragment` and `SomeOtherFragment`. We replace `ListFragment` with `SomeOtherFragment` (saving in back stack) and then go back. After that we see, that position that `ListFragment` is scrolled on is the same.

But I don't understand, why.

I don't see any code in `ListFragment`'s source which mantain scrolling position. `onDestroyView` is called, inner `ListView` is recreated. How does it work? Please point me to a piece of code.

Comment: try looking into `onSavedInstance()` which manages and provides the `Bundle savedInstanceState` you get in your `onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState)` call.

Comment: Here is ListFragment's source: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/app/ListFragment.java?av=f. I don't see any special processing of savedInstanceState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't find saving state in ListFragment or ListActivity cause all process of storing position is done in ListView. ListFragment simply make a use of ListView. When you open AbsListView.java you can take a look at two methods.

```
@Override Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    [...]
        if (selectedId >= 0) {
            // Remember the selection
            ss.viewTop = mSelectedTop;
            ss.position = getSelectedItemPosition();
            ss.firstId = INVALID_POSITION;
}
```

and place where these values are restored

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        [...]
        if (ss.selectedId >= 0) {
             mNeedSync = true;
             mPendingSync = ss;
             mSyncRowId = ss.selectedId;
             mSyncPosition = ss.position;
             mSpecificTop = ss.viewTop;
             mSyncMode = SYNC_SELECTED_POSITION;
}
```

You can take a look at source code by yoursefl here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/widget/AbsListView.java/

Comment: Thanks! But I still can't understand. Fragment's content view is recreated, `onCreateView` and `ensureList` has been called, so `mList` is completely new object. How did it take state from previous?

Comment: View itself is recreated it's true. But when view is created again all  stored data is pass to this new object.

Comment: But how? `onCreateView` calls `inflater.inflate` don't use `savedInstanceState`; `onViewCreated` calls base method, which is empty, and `ensureList`. `ensureList` also don't use `savedInstanceState`. How new objects get instanceState from previous? Or it is a kind of Android magic?

Comment: View handle saving state by itself. Check methods dispatchSaveInstanceState and dispatchSaveInstanceState in View.java class